# How can I make a list populate multiple columns instead of scrolling in AutoHotKey?

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

I have a script that lists open windows in AutoHotKey. I'd prefer to be able to view them all at once rather than have to scroll. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

How are you generating the list? Are you using a `ListBox`? If so, you can set the number of rows to be whatever you need. If not, please specify or post your code.

```
nWindows := 5 , sWindowList := "File Explorer|Outlook|AutoHotkey Help|Firefox|Excel"
Gui , Add , ListBox , r%nWindows% vWindowList , %sWindowList%
Gui , Show
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm#ListBox